# How to remove upto {(nth occurance of a pattern in string) or (nth part of concatenated string)} in Groovy?

Tags: git, groovy

The `git describe --always --dirty`command returns an output similar to 
`my_tag-42-githash-dirty`.

I want to extract only the `githash-dirty` info, i.e delete all characters before that.

I did `git describe --match=NeVMatcH --always --dirty` as a work around. But I want another solution, for example using pattern substitution in Groovy. Or maybe another dedicated git command. How can I achieve it?

Also, sometimes, my git tags would have a `-` in them as well. Like `my-tag-42-githash-dirty`

Comment: why not use `git rev-parse HEAD` if you are only interrested in the commit id?

Comment: Can you try explaining it without the git reference?  What strings do you **have**?  Do you have several examples?  What strings do you **want** from each example?  What code have you tried?  Where are you having problems?

Comment: @cfrick I need the dirty information also.

Comment: @tim_yates I am not sure I can explain it without the git reference. This git command gives 4 pieces of information separated by `-`. I want to extract only the last 2 parts of information. I tried something like `replaceAll(".*-","")` but it does't work. This shows only the last part. I want to stop removing content after the second part.

Comment: then i'd use the exit code from `git diff-index --quiet HEAD` to see if it's dirty. asking git for exact things will provide more reliable results than parsing a string where at least at one point a human can put any kind of nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to agree with the comments about asking git instead of post-processing, but if you really need to process this using groovy you can do something like:

```
git describe --always --dirty | groovy -e "print System.in.text.tokenize('-').takeRight(2).join('-')"
```

which prints:

```
g6d67059-dirty
```

I.e. take the input string from System.in, tokenize the string on dash `-` which gives you a list `['my','tag','42','githash','dirty']`, take the two rightmost elements in the list and join them using dash.

I wouldn't call this robust, but it does work for your example data.